# For which values of $n$ integral $\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n \ln{x}} dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, analysis

For which values of $n$ integral
$$\int_{3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^n \ln{x}} dx$$
converges?

This is an improper integral, but since we integrate from $3$ , does it mean that we don't care about $ln$ being $0$ and only care about power of $x$?
In this case does it mean that for $n$ large enough(?) it is convergent?

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n > 1$, then

$$\int_3^{\infty} \frac1{x^n \ln x} \, dx < \int_3^{\infty} \frac1{x^n } \, dx = \frac1{n-1}3^{1-n}< \infty.$$

If $n = 1$, then

$$\int_3^{\infty} \frac1{x \ln x} \, dx =\left.\ln(\ln x)\right|_3^{\infty} =\infty.$$

Can you figure out the case where $n < 1$?

Comment: between $0$ and $1$ it would still be $\infty$, at $0$ it would be  $0$ and $<0$ it  would be $\infty$ again?

Comment: @John Lennon: It will diverge for any $n < 1$ since in that case $x^n < x$.  By the comparison test $\int 1/(x^n \ln x) > \int 1/ (x \ln x)$ and we already showed the second integral diverges.